# Teams Activity Notification For Personal Tab Teams App

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Looking to a point in the right direction for a project I am working on. Currently, we have a teams app that is installed and there is a personal tab in it that opens up a list of courses to be taken on our platform, the user can then click on the course they want to do and it opens in an iframe within teams and they can take it.

The next task is to notify them into their activity tab within teams when they have been targeted with a new course, I am not sure if this can be accomplished by using the graph API or if I am going to have to go down the proactive messages route. Anyone that has a demo of what they have done for something similar would be great.

Comment: Please have a look at this sample. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/csharp
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: I will get a look into these examples, my main use case is to notify the users when they have been targeted by content on an external platform and send them to the teams personal tab to complete it. So would need to be able to call from outside of teams and let them know the content is there.